# Javascript - URL Decoding for an unstructured URL

Tags: javascript, string, decodeuricomponent

I have a URL that looks something like this after decoding using decodeURIComponent

```
https://secretStar.22.test.com/l/{"mode":"test","app":"revenue:app","param2":1,"loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://revenue:app":"unique_identifier"},"pathPrefix":"","xx":1}/script22.js
```

Now, I would like to extract few details from this URL , for Ex:

```
mode = test
app =  revenue:app
param2 = 1
appMarkupRevenueApp = unique identifier
scriptName = script.js
```

I could have extracted it using qs params if these values were qs params. I was able to extract the information by writing a function that splits and joins and then splits again but that is not very efficient when it comes to extracting these params from more than 4k urls in a csv file.

Is there a better way to extract these? I can think of regex but I am not very familiar with that and could not get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by matching the embedded JSON and then turning that into an object, perhaps with something like this:

```
JSON.parse(foo.match(/({.+})[^}]+/)[1])
```

The regex `/({.+})[^}]+/` creates a group by matching a `{` followed by anything at all, followed by `}` and then matches only if the group is followed by something that isn't `}`

The JSON is parsing the first matched group.

There is one problem, that I'm not sure is due to your question having a typo or something to do with `decodeURIComponent`:

In your expected output you have:

```
appMarkupRevenueApp = unique identifier
```

However your data has:

```
"APPLICATION@markup://revenue:app":"unique_identifier"
```

This is quite a mismatch and it is not obvious which is correct

Small demo:

```js
var string = 'https://secretStar.22.test.com/l/{"mode":"test","app":"revenue:app","param2":1,"loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://revenue:app":"unique_identifier"},"pathPrefix":"","xx":1}/script22.js';

var data = JSON.parse(string.match(/({.+})[^}]+/)[1]);

for(key of Object.keys(data)) { console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`) }
```

Comment: @A-D not sure about that appMarkupRevenue, something wierd is going on there

Comment: yeah, loaded returns an object and I can pull the value from there.